# Reinstall windows 8 upgrade with a windows 8 oem disk?

Tags: windows, windows-8, upgrade

I have a windows 7 PC that I upgraded to windows 8 pro awhile back. This PC has been having some issues so I wanted to do a clean install, but I didn't make an ISO image of the windows 8 upgrade when I downloaded it. I do have a windows 8 system builder disk though from a different PC I built. Is it possible to do a clean install of my upgrade using the "system builder" disk and my upgrade key? I read some posts from a year ago saying you can do a clean install using the upgrade CD but didn't know if the system builder could be used instead to accomplish the same thing?
Thanks

Comment: Yes; You could even use the disk select "Clean Install" over your current system.  You could also just use the "Reset" feature and get the exact same results.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know if "reset" would work with the underlying windows 7 restore partition and all, but if so that sounds easiest.

Comment: Well I assume you don't care to migrate back to Windows 7 then upgrade to Windows 8.0 then to 8.1.  You can do that, and use the upgrade key, with the system builder disk; yes

Comment: Assuming a clean install isn't an option i'm definitely fine with the 3 part re-install. Just wanted to make sure I wouldn't get stuck and have to repurchase since I have no actual "upgrade" disk. Thanks

Comment: Provided you have an actual upgrade license and you could in theory download the disk if you wanted your fine.  You cannot "upgrade" Windows 7 to Windows 8 with any other license ( except a Windows 8.1 license I suppose ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a clean install of Windows 8.1 Pro on my machine using a previously purchased Windows 8 *upgrade* key.

First, I downloaded the full 8.1 ISO using [this](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/33164-how-download-windows-8-1-iso.html) procedure. I used my own *upgrade* key to initiate the download.

Then I installed 8.1 Pro using a generic "trial" key for Pro version

```
XHQ8N-C3MCJ-RQXB6-WCHYG-C9WKB
```

This installs a non-activated trial version of Windows 8.1 Pro.

And then I activated that freshly installed version using my *upgrade* key. It all worked without any problems.

So, my suggestion would be to forget about any disks you might have. Download the full ISO from Microsoft, install it and then activate it with your key.

But if you insist on using your system builder disks specifically, you might find yourself in a situation when system builder disk refuses to accept an upgrade key. In that case you might try using the "trial" key for installation and then using your upgrade key for activation.

Comment: Once installed the Windows 8 Pro installation will accept any `Windows 8.x Pro` key.  The installer might reject it but thats what the generic key is for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working in my scenario. I used belarc advisor to retrieve my windows 8 pro upgrade key, reset my system to original windows 7, then popped in my windows 8 pro system builder disk. It asked to grab updates via web, if I wanted to wipe all settings, and then asked for my key. I typed in my upgrade key and it started preparing the install. It Went smooth enough that I'll probably end up doing this to our other "upgraded" PC's. I ended up not needing the trial key but it gives confidence if something would of went wrong. thanks